# android emulator with serial port

Tags: android, android-emulator, serial-port

I am trying to develop and application who connects to a serial port. For that, I am following this api:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-serialport-api/

https://github.com/cepr/android-serialport-api

When I run the application in a real device it works, but when run in the android emulator, no serial ports are shown in the setup activity.

I am doing the following steps to run the emulator:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_23 -qemu  -serial COM1
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe wait-for-device
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe shell chmod 666 /dev/ttyS2
```

Similiar to this link:

https://github.com/cepr/android-serialport-api/blob/master/android-serialport-api/project/run_emulator.sh

I am using a Nexus 5 emulator, Should I choose another emulator? 
What I am doing wrong? What I am missing?

Comment: Is the setup activity in Android?

Comment: I don't understand your question, the applicacion has an Activity called SetupActivity, where the available serial ports of the device should be displayed. I suppose the emulator should be configured in order to emulate serial ports, but I don't know how to do it, because commands above doesn't work for me.

Comment: oh, this is an android application. it was a bit unclear. I understand now

Comment: @adrian4aes any luck ?